# Where is the hard drive on an Acer Chromebook CB5-311?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I recently had a display/main-board failure on my [CB5-311 Chromebook](http://us.hardware.info/productinfo/263928/acer-chromebook-cb5-311-t0z8/specifications).

I wanted to give it in for warranty, but there is only replacement, not repair.

So I wanted to make a backup of the hard-drive, but when I opened the CB5-311, I didn't find it. This is the first time this happened to me. I've had 5 laptops before that, and I never had even the least problems finding the hard-drive.

My 3 colleagues in office couldn't help me either.

Can anyone point me to **WHERE** the hard-drive is on this board **(the big black 4 cells is the battery, not the drive)**?

[image: Acer CB5-311]

Comment: The page you link to says that the machine has an SSD not a hard drive. Perhaps it is incorporated into the motherboard.

Comment: @Keith Miller: Yes, that was my guess as well.

Comment: Looks like it uses eMMC. There's a picture here: http://www.howtogeek.com/196541/emmc-vs.-ssd-not-all-solid-state-storage-is-equal/ You won't be able to remove it and it's probably encrypted.

Comment: i dont thinks its protected with encryption, like in android, there is a setting to turn that on, but like others are telling its soldered to motherboard like most slim devices these days, my current asus laptop has 2GB soldered ram on motherbord

Comment: you can think of chromebooks as the new netbooks but with tablet components (ARM processor etc)

Comment: @wiak: All chromebook partitions are encrypted.